# Adding/removing class to anchor tag with jQuery- twitter bootsrap buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I have a single page site. My navigation consists of a few buttons styled by bootstrap 3.

Since it is a single page, the buttons are anchor tags. I want to be able to have an `.active` class applied to the last anchor tag that has been clicked.

This is my HTML:

```
<a href="#home">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home
    </button>
</a>

<a href="#about">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> About
    </button>
</a>
```

And my CSS:

```
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
border:none;
background-color: #2C3E50;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2C3E50;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function() {
        $(".btn-default.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).find(".btn-default").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

or...

```
$(function() {
    $("a").on("click", function() {
        $("a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Not sure if the active class should be added to the link or the enclosed button, so there's 1 for each.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`jQuery addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$('a#buttonid').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

You'd check to make sure it doesn't already have that class and remove the active class from the other buttons aswell.